# Real use case dynamic (computed) property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A dynamic property:

```
var obj = {
  // Computed (dynamic) property names
  [ 'prop_' + (() => 42)() ]: 42
};
```

This is of course very fancy. But where could someone use this without adding unnecessary complexity?

Comment: could it not be used to calculate a value of a property which represents the price + tax or similar?

Comment: @SamHolder That would be a real dynamic property, but the OP is talking about dynamic property names, from the example in the question.

Comment: Have a look at our canonical [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/1048572) and all its linked questions for an overview of use cases

Comment: Okay... And now I just used it myself:) `{
              [match.isHomeMatch ? 'home' : 'away']: own(),
              [match.isHomeMatch ? 'away' : 'home']: theirs()
            }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a property name as a constant:

```
var obj = { [SOME_CONSTANT]: 42 };
```

Answer (score 6):

One case where I wanted it was where property names for JSON were defined in generated files, based off Java classes.

```
// Generated
var SomeJsonBodyParams = {NAME: 'name', ID: 'id', ETA, 'estimatedTimeOfArrival'};

// Using it
sendAjax('some/url', {
    [SomeJsonBodyParams.NAME] = userData.name,
    ...
});
```

We even had a method so we could kind of do it

```
function makeObj() {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i+=2) {
      obj[i] = obj[i+i];
  }
  return obj;
}

sendAjax('some/url', makeObj(
    SomeJsonBodyParams.NAME, userData.name,
    ...
));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use it in `class` and with [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol):

```
class MyClass {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        // my iterator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have:

```
var hi = 'hi';
var test = 'test';
var hello = 'hello';
```

Instead of:

```
var object = {};

object[hi] = 111;
object[test] = 222;
object[hello] = 333;
```

You could write it in a much shorter syntax:

```
var object = {
    [hi]: 111,
    [test]: 222,
    [hello]: 333
}
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g. it could be used when you want to use a, let's say, constant as a key in object.

```
const DATA_TYPE = {
    PERSON: 'person',
    COMPANY: 'company'
};

let cache = {
    [DATA_TYPE.PERSON]: getPerson()
};
```

And later access:

```
cache[DATA_TYPE.PERSON]
```

Instead of `DATA_TYPE.PERSON` could be anything (including some real-time calculated values).